# How to hold hexadecimal values in Scala?

Tags: scala, hex

I have a hexadecimal value like this

```
0000030000010000010000020000090000030000040000070000EF
```

How can I store it in Scala?

Comment: conversion is fine. but how do i store it as hexadecimal?

Comment: Since "hexadecimal" is a string representation of numbers, you can only store it as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigInt). Usage example:

```
scala> val i = BigInt("0000030000010000010000020000090000030000040000070000EF", 16)
i: scala.math.BigInt = 18831305580304483748966372317094081267935079240643756687599

scala> i.toString(16)
res3: String = 30000010000010000020000090000030000040000070000ef
```